Terraform json content output is showing along with escape characters
I am trying to fetch json content from azure function app and saving the output to a file. But somehow it is appending escape characters in each line. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.
Below is the sample json
        {
            "alias": "XXX-ED",
            "name": "XXX-ED | XXX Cloud | Dev/Test",
            "prefix": "xxxed",
            "id": 12345,
            "cluster": 3,
            "ZoneName": "East US 2",
            "EnvironmentName": "Dev/Test"
         }

terraform code
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type = string
  description = "nameof resource group name"
}


data "azurerm_windows_function_app" "az_function" {
  name                = "xxx"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_function_app_host_keys" "az_function_key"{
  name = "xxx"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

locals {
  func_uri = "https://${data.azurerm_windows_function_app.az_function.default_hostname}/api/xxx/?code=${data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.az_function_key.default_function_key}"
}

data "http" "http_data" {
  url = local.func_uri
  #module.function_app.uri
  method = "GET"

  request_headers = {
    Accept = "application/json"
  }
}

resource "local_file" "config" {
  content = data.http.http_data.response_body
  filename = "xxxconfig.json"
}

output "uri" {
  value = local_file.config.filename
}

output file
[
  "{",
  "\t\"Clients\":[",
  "\t\t{",
  "\t\t\t\"alias\": \"XXX-ED\",",
  "\t\t\t\"name\": \"XXX-ED | XXX Cloud | Dev/Test\",",
  "\t\t\t\"prefix\": \"xxxed\",",
  "\t\t\t\"id\": 12345,",
  "\t\t\t\"cluster\": 3,",
  "\t\t\t\"ZoneName\": \"East US 2\",",
  "\t\t\t\"EnvironmentName\": \"Dev/Test\","
    ]",
  "}"
]


You can try maybe with content = jsondecode(data.http.http_data.response_body).

No, that one didn't help. But when I checked this url link , I found json content should be uploaded in compressed format. I did the same and it worked. Thanks for your help though.
